# Different animation an css for element on pageload

Tags: jquery, css, animation, pageload

I'm wondering if it's possible to do and I'm not sure if I can explain my problem right but here goes:

Depending on which page link I click, the element in page that loads will be animated differently. Example:

If I click a link on page A -> page C loads and the element slides from the top
If I click a link on page B -> page C loads and the element slides from the bottom

Hope that's clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement different sripts on site a or b. Or you could check in your javascript on which page you currently are.
Using animations is not a big deal in jquery:

- http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/
  documentation for slideDown effect.
- http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/
  documentation for slideUp effect.

both are simple to use and will give you the pretty effect to your page which is easy to do and pretty looks good.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm already familiar with those effects, but just couldn't figure out how to implement this check. I'm guessing that checking the page address would be a bit problematic because it regards to lots of different pages.

Comment: why ? you could use document.location to get your current url

Comment: yeah you're probably right, but I'm quite a noob in programming :/ so how can this be done? how can I check from what page was I redirected? I would really appreciate some more details.

Comment: You cannot check if you were redirected in Javascript because Javascript is only running in the browser and not on the server.

Comment: Ok, still have no idea how to make it work in the browser but thanks anyway ;-)

Comment: you could do that with javascript or jquery ! You are able to load specific pages or parts of pages using AJAX

Comment: I don't think we understood each other ;-) I am trying to do it with jquery from the beginning just don't know how because I am new to programming. Answering that it can be done by jquery doesn't really help that much :P

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7684/discussion-between-evilp-and-tomarz)